# Neo4j not able to start using apoc plugin

Tags: database, docker, neo4j

Getting this error while starting the neo4j docker, I am on linux server

> ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on 0.0.0.0:7474.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /data/databases
> at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:255) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:193) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:164) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:85) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:30) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry@2fd954f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to register procedure, because the name `apoc.atomic.add` is already in use.".
> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:370) ~[neo4j-common-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:246) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> ... 5 more
> Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.ProcedureException: Unable to register procedure, because the name `apoc.atomic.add` is already in use.
> at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.ProcedureRegistry.register(ProcedureRegistry.java:84) ~[neo4j-procedure-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.register(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:145) ~[neo4j-procedure-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.register(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:89) ~[neo4j-procedure-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.procedure.impl.GlobalProceduresRegistry.start(GlobalProceduresRegistry.java:340) ~[neo4j-procedure-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:353) ~[neo4j-common-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:92) ~[neo4j-common-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:246) ~[neo4j-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
> ... 5 more

Answer (score 0):

An error message like "Unable to register procedure, because the name apoc.atomic.add is already in use." usually indicates that there are multiple APOC plugins.

Check your docker configuration to make sure it does not install multiple APOC plugins.